# Performance optimization for long text in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, performance

In my app users can make comments in different ways (e.g. from email). To limit the length of the comments is not an option. Some comments are several millions characters long which makes Comment component to render them for around 2-4 seconds.

Is there any known way of optimization I can use to reduce this time?

Comments can be as HTML or plain text.

Answer (score 0):

The optimal way to do this is to set a maximum initial render to the comment let us say 30 chars this will go for all of the next solutions

#### Solution 1:

then add a **see more...** button to let the user selectively expand the desired comment.

#### Solution 2:

you can also make a separate view to the comment if possible

another page/ view to render the full comment

---

if the above 2 solutions don't fit then you will have to deal with the loading time and add extra Loaders/ indicators to help the user assess the waiting time

Comment: That works and I already use it. The problem starts when user is expanding comment. It freezes component for few seconds, so what I'm asking for is something like **react-virtualized**, but for plain text

Comment: can you expand the 1st solution more and what I mean is that you load 1000 chars per see more click

Comment: or make it load more text as the user scrolls till the text ends

Comment: what if content is HTML?

Comment: There should be something to load in multiple parts lists, large text, images etc

Comment: You should let the backend handle breaking up the page depending on the content